# Importing or Including XSLT files from a resource

Tags: c#, xslt

I'm working on an app where there are a number of XSL stylesheets in use. These stylesheets are stored as resources in the DLL.

I want to include or import another stylesheet in to the running one. Now, I can make this work if the included stylesheet is in the same folder as the running one, but I need to include one in a *different* folder.

```
<xsl:include href ="../Folder/transform.xslt"/>
```

causes an error to be thown when the containing stylesheet is loaded. The server looks to c:\Windows\Folder\transform.xslt which, obviously, isn't there.

Can anyopne suggest how I do this? mI can find next to nothing about running a transform from an enbedded resource and, sadly, I have no choice but to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly how it would go, but I theorize it would be done by [passing a custom `XmlResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163427.aspx) to load the references from resources.

Implement a class that inherits from [`XmlResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlresolver.aspx) and looks in resources instead of the filesystem (which would be location the default [`XmlUrlResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlurlresolver.aspx) would look to).

---

Update: It looks like MSDN has had this problem before.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302284.aspx for an example of how to implement a custom XmlResolver.

Comment: Thx for that. I was just about to post that I've tried a couple of examples of this that I've found, but none seem to like the idea of looking in a different folder.

Comment: I don't think you should be hitting the disk directly in any case.  I just updated the post with an example that allows use of a res:// namespace to allow resolution of resources.